# How to grep files and redirect output to a CSV in Linux?

Tags: linux, csv

I have got the following directory structure:

```
/releases/customer1/filesNeeded/file1.xml
/releases/customer1/filesNeeded/subfolder/file2.xml
/releases/customer2/filesNeeded/file1.xml
/releases/customer2/filesNeeded/subfolder/file2.xml
```

And so on.

In file1.xml I have got -parameter1 value -parameter2 value and so on. I need to create a script that loops through each customer, and first ask if the 'filesNeeded' folder is present. In case it is, I need to grep each parameter value and output these values to a single CSV file.

Any ideas?

Comment: sure. shows us the code you have so far. it's unclear which part is problematic to you.

Comment: Show us your code, xml sample and any error output. You need only file1.xml or and file2.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Folder structure as you mentioned, content for each file as shown :

**/releases/customer1/filesNeeded/file1.xml**

```
sdshsjsd -parameter1 value1 jksdj -parameter2 value2 jdskjdks
sdshsjsd -parameter20 value20 jksdj -parameter21 value21 jdskjdks
sdshsjsd -parameter22 value22 jksdj -parameter23 value23 jdskjdks
sdshsjsd -parameter24 value24 jksdj -parameter25 value25 jdskjdks
```

**/releases/customer1/filesNeeded/subfolder/file2.xml**

```
lskdlskd -parameter6 value6 ljl
```

**/releases/customer2/filesNeeded/file1.xml**

```
sdkhdsh -parameter12 value12 jksdj -parameter15 value15
```

**/releases/customer2/filesNeeded/subfolder/file2.xml**

```
kdsjkjsd -parameter17 value17
kdsjkjsd -parameter100 value100 -parameter value
kdsjkjsd -parameter170 value170
```

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while true;
do

  # checking if customerN directory present #
  if [ -d customer$i ]
  then

    # Cleanup for previously present csv file, if any #
    if [ -f customer$i.csv ]
    then
      rm customer$i.csv
    fi

    echo ""
    echo "Checking in customer$i folder";
    if [ -d customer$i/filesNeeded ]
    then

      j=1
      num_files=`find customer$i/filesNeeded -type f -name "*.xml" | wc -l`
      echo "  Number of valid files in customer$i/filesNeeded directory = $num_files"
      while [ $j -le $num_files ]
      do

        file_name=`find customer$i/filesNeeded -type f -name "*.xml" | head -n $j | tail -n 1`
        echo "    Processing file : $file_name"
        cat $file_name | tr -s " " | sed -r 's/-parameter[0-9]+/\n/g' | grep "^ " | cut -d " " -f 2 >> tmp_customer$i.csv

        j=$[ $j + 1 ]
      done
    fi

  else
    break;
  fi

  cat tmp_customer$i.csv | tr '\n' ',' > customer$i.csv
  rm tmp_customer$i.csv

  i=$[ $i + 1 ]
done
```

**Output Files Generated:**

customer1.csv

```
value1,value2,value20,value21,value22,value23,value24,value25,value6,
```

customer2.csv

```
value12,value15,value17,value100,value170,
```

Hope this helps!